# Where I could get small UP,Down,Delete Icons

Tags: icons, igoogle

I want to get small up,down,delete icons like igoogle todo list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Famfamfam produces the Silk icon set, which I use a lot: http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/

Answer (score 0):

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Icons

Answer (score 0):

In August 2012, six years ago but already twenty months after this thread was opened and answered, the first version of [**Font Awesome**](https://fontawesome.com/) was released. The current version is 5.2 and it includes about 4000 icons, some ones [free](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free) and some others [for *pro only*](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=pro). Arrows as in this questions are also among the free ones.